# NSString blowing my mind away

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have three `NSString` properties declared like this:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *currentPassword;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *newPassword;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *confirmPassword;
```

I initialize them in a `viewDidLoad` method:

```
currentPassword = [[NSString alloc]init];
newPassword = [[NSString alloc]init];
confirmPassword = [[NSString alloc]init];
```

The funny thing is that they are the same object after initialize them as different objects!

[image]

Is this some kind of compiler optimization?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As NSString objects are immutable (i.e. cannot be changed after they are created) and there's no sense in creating several different instances of the same immutable strings, system tries to reuse existing objects whenever possible.

Using constructor with no parameters may be one of examples. You can also check that `+stringWithString:` (and `-initWithString:`) also return the (retained) parameter string, and `copy` method in `NSString` is equivalent to `retain`.

Remember that optimization is only possible because we know NSString instance is not going to change and the same tests with `NSMutableString` most likely will to create new string instances.

P.S. About NSAssert usage:

> **NSAssert** Generates an assertion if a given condition is false.

So your assert condition should be reversed:

```
NSAssert(currentPassword && newPassword && confirmPassword,@"nil field");
```

Comment: I suspected that. Do you see anything wrong with the assertion?

Comment: Im so dumb, the conditions are wrong, I should check that they're not nil. It fails because they are not obviously nil.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this some kind of compiler optimization?

Not quite. It's a special case value for a constant, and an optimization of a common concrete immutable type/value which has been implemented by the `NSString` class.

`NSString` is immutable. There's no reason multiple instances of the same empty string are needed. In such simple cases, `-[NSString init]` can take the form:

```
static NSString* const EmptyNSString = @"";

- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  [self release];
  return EmptyNSString;
}
```

similarly, `+ [NSString string]`:

```
+ (id)string
{
  return EmptyNSString;
}
```

So there are a few static immutable objects which are used this way where it makes sense. Other obvious examples include `+ [NSArray array]` and `+ [NSNumber numberWithBool:]`.

Each one of these constants can represent what would have been many many many thousands of unique allocations produced during your program's execution.

This happens to work because `NSString` as a class cluster: You are returned an object of one of many opaque types which implements the interface declared by `NSString`. Therefore, a `NSMutableString` type could then implement `init` appropriately:

```
- (id)init
{
  self = [super init];
  if (nil != self) { ... }
  return self;
}
```

Finally, you should in almost all cases declare your `NSString` properties as `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have NSString as a property you should specify the attribute 'copy' instead.

Comment: @frowing: It does, and usually it doesn't really matter much, but you'll get in trouble when you use NSMutableString.

Answer (score 0):

NSString is defined as an immutable type, so whenever the compiler can optimize things by combining identical strings, it should.  if you use `@"myString"` in two separate places in your code, they will be referencing the very same object. `@""` strings are of class NSConstantString